# Sharepoint 2007 Windows Gadget

Tags: 2007, list, development, javascript, web-services

I am trying to develop a Gadget for Sharepoint 2007, which will authenticate a user and then fetch him a sharepoint list from a specific URL,

For the last 4 days I have been working on it and came across different ways of making it, but because solutions are either half done, dont work or too confusing to get help from or convert into what I want.

Because Windows Gadget uses Scripting + HTML  so I have following options to carry on work with to make this gadget,

- Create a Visual studio project (dll) which will fetch the list for me using Object Model of Sharepoint and then I can use JavaScript & Visual Studio "COM" to read that dll ("Classes") and get data in JavaScript + displaying it on HTML.
  Problem with this approach is, I am not sure, If I create a "dll" with Sharepoint clients object model and put it into the gadget folder, will it work on Clients (that dont have sharepoint installed on there PCs). 
  While trying to find help regarding this approach to problem I find this project that is doing kinda same thing, but not really sure if i make changes to it and it will gonna work with "dll" I was talking about earlier, here's the Link to Gadget,

[Gmail Gadget Using JavaScript to Read Visual studio Dll](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17408/NET-Interop-for-Gadgets-A-C-GMail-Inbox-Reader-Ex)

- Second Approach to solve the problem can be, If I use Sharepoint webservices, that will get me all the List Items, but then using Webservices in JavaScript isn't that easy, so if i create a Visual Studio Project, get a web reference to sharepoint webservices, and return a list, which I again use JavaScript to read the results out of DLL, and display them on HTML.

[This Link is Using Webservices in a Dot Net Project to Update a List Item, but In comments it also tells how to get List data, but then how I gonna authenticate my users](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/8e4edf0f-19d7-4d3f-8086-e615b9be2681/)

- Another solution is to use Jquery to get sharepoint List data, like in link before, but again, how can i authenticate my users @ gadget ?

[Using jQuery to fetch List Data](http://mydevexperience.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/sharepoint-list-access-part-i-how-to-access-sharepoint-list-web-service-using-jquery-entirely-client-side-only/)

- My Favorite solution is to Use SOAP or REST along with webservices,  I want to use SOAP to get Sharepoint List data and authenticate my users at the same time, I find hundreds of tutorials on this, but non of them actually doing authenticating or telling how this can work in a Gadget, using JavaScript/HTML,
- There is few Gadget I found Online that are somehow related to what I need, they either dont work, or can't be changed to what I want.

  [Datapolis Sharepoint List Gadget, simply doesn't work on my PC, altho its exactly what I am looking for, possible reason is, it doesn't work for SSL/https](http://datapolis.com/products/sharepointlistgadget.aspx)

[A gadget that is getting News Feed from a website, its sending an HTTPxml request but then asking for a RSS feed, whereas i dont have Rss feedback in sharepoint site I am working on](http://www.blockcoders.net/creating-xml-based-gadget-windows-7)

Cheers for reading this I hope you either gonna increase your knowledge or gonna share it :)

Comment: You posted the same question to [stackoverflow where I suggested an answer to it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10651437/623816). It would be probably worth merging both topics to one place. (If I knew how :-) --- Ferda

Comment: How is this off topic?

Comment: exactly :/, maybe @Anders Rask didn't read my question properly

Comment: Windows Gadgets is clearly off-topic so there is a low probability to get a good answer here (which i guess is why you cross posted in SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/10651437/623816 ). I have re-opened it, but will close it again if it receives no answers

Comment: @AndersRask my question somewhere asking how to access a Sharepoint list using Webservices(server side) & XMLHTTPResponse (on client side) including authentication for users, which does make sense to me as a Sharepoint developer, am sorry but am disappointed by your explanation

Comment: You might want to rephrase it then to be a bit more "on topic" instead of linking out to various articles.

Comment: @PirateEric because this question needed a lot of explanation, so I had to make it clear and added all the confusions I had into it, I wonder why people always look for negative things to point out to be honest ?

Comment: I'm not trying to be negative, I'm trying to help you get answers to your question(s). You might want to break it up into several questions specifically targetted with the particular issue. It'll be easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: @PirateEric I agree with you there, I tried that before but then people ask me they need more explanation, but I will keep your advise in my mind, thanks :)

Comment: @TimeToThine long and elaborate questions does not guarantee answers, on the contrary a long question with alot of links will scare off most readers from even reading the Q.

Comment: @AndersRask Sure, I will keep it in my mind for future questions, cheers

Comment: I think you should follow @PirateEric's recommendation and clean up the question. Here is some guides from our FAQ: [What if i dont get answers](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty) and [How to ask](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: We are closing this question - it is very general, it has been cross-posted, has no answer, the OP has moved on. If anyone wants it opened again please flag it giving reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible in our Scenario, so I stopped working on this project.